# Using dictionary for automated tests

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to test my web application with selenium webdriver c#. Right now I am watching tutorials.

```
        IWebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
        chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:////link//login");

        IWebElement element = chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("usernamexpath"));
        element.SendKeys("  ");

        element = chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("passwordxpath"));
        element.SendKeys("  ");
```

There is a code something like this. In here I will test the login page. For this purpose I want to create a dictionary. It will hold all the xpaths in my app with that dictionary so I will not look for xpath again and again. The problem is I am not sure if should I use dictionary for it. Is there any other technic that you recommend? Or should I create a class for dictionary and use it like this;

```
        XPaths path = new XPaths(); //dictonary class
        IWebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
        chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:////link//login");

        IWebElement element = chrome.FindElement(By.XPath(path.usernamefield));
        element.SendKeys("  ");

        element = chrome.FindElement(By.XPath(path.passwordfield));
        element.SendKeys("  ");
```

Comment: Personally I like test methods to be as self-contained as possible.  That said, if you're going to be using the same paths in other test methods then I'd suggest just having a static class with fields, which more suits your 2nd code example...  `path.username`, rather than `path["username"]`.  If you don't *actually* mean `Dictionary`, then I say yes (just remove the word `field`) :)

Comment: What is the reason behind using static for this?

Comment: Just so you don't have to create an instance.  If you don't need a functional object then just make everything static.

Comment: Actually, I misspoke.  I didn't mean literally a static class.  A class with static fields is what I'd do... https://dotnetfiddle.net/jbYQSw

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @gufi? If so, I'd like to hear what you have implemented. Thanks!